# MySql Use of Max on Date for Aging Report with excluding a specific condition

Tags: php, mysql

I need to prepare a forecast aging report for projects finishing in coming months. Data lied in various tables - all having a common `post_id` field. Lets see my table structure first (I will mention only relevant columns).

- table1 : 01c_posts (ID, post_title,......)
- table2 : 01c_project (id, post_id, end_date, .....)
- table3 : 01c_enquairy_products (id, post_id, confirmed_amount, .....)
- table4 : 01c_update (id, post_id, status_id, status_date,.....)
- table5 : 01c_status (status_id, status, .....)

`01c_update` having multiple status for every `post_id.

Now, I have prepared following SQL which has no error but giving multiple lines for every project according to the numbers of their status in `update table` - so the `sum` of `confirmed_amount` in `table3` will be multiple of number of status for relevant project.

```
    SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1;
    select a.post_id, b.post_title, 
    sum(if(month(a.end_date) = 1 and year(a.end_date) = 2018,c.confirmed_price, 0)) as "Jan", 
    sum(if(month(a.end_date) = 2 and year(a.end_date) = 2018,c.confirmed_price, 0)) as "Feb", 
    sum(if(month(a.end_date) = 3 and year(a.end_date) = 2018, c.confirmed_price, 0)) as "Mar", 
    sum(if(month(a.end_date) = 4 and year(a.end_date) = 2018, c.confirmed_price, 0)) as "Apr", 
    sum(if(month(a.end_date) = 5 and year(a.end_date) = 2018, c.confirmed_price, 0)) as "May", 
    sum(if(month(a.end_date) = 6 and year(a.end_date) = 2018, c.confirmed_price, 0)) as "Jun", 
    sum(if(month(a.end_date) = 7 and year(a.end_date) = 2018, c.confirmed_price, 0)) as "Jul", 
    sum(if(month(a.end_date) = 8 and year(a.end_date) = 2018, c.confirmed_price, 0)) as "Aug",

    max(d.update_date), d.status_id
    from 01c_projects a 
    inner join 01c_posts b on a.post_id = b.ID 
    inner join 01c_enquairy_product c on a.post_id = c.post_id 
    inner join 01c_updates d on a.post_id = d.post_id 
    where a.post_id not in (select post_id from 01c_updates where status_id = 25 or status_id = 24)
    group by b.post_title
    having max(d.update_date)
    order by a.end_date
```

Can someone guide me where i'm missing?

Comment: Maybe `GROUP BY b.post_id` instead of `b.post_title`?

Comment: every post have a unique title, problem is somewhere in max(update_date) - it should take one date only which has a maximum value for a specific post_id, but its taking all date entries and increasing number of rows

Answer (score 0):

ok, got is resolved. Final solution is given below so other can get a help if needed

```
    select a.post_id, b.post_title, 
sum(if(month(a.end_date) = 1 and year(a.end_date) = 2018,c.confirmed_price, 0)) as "Jan", 
sum(if(month(a.end_date) = 2 and year(a.end_date) = 2018,c.confirmed_price, 0)) as "Feb", 
sum(if(month(a.end_date) = 3 and year(a.end_date) = 2018, c.confirmed_price, 0)) as "Mar", 
sum(if(month(a.end_date) = 4 and year(a.end_date) = 2018, c.confirmed_price, 0)) as "Apr", 
sum(if(month(a.end_date) = 5 and year(a.end_date) = 2018, c.confirmed_price, 0)) as "May", 
sum(if(month(a.end_date) = 6 and year(a.end_date) = 2018, c.confirmed_price, 0)) as "Jun", 
sum(if(month(a.end_date) = 7 and year(a.end_date) = 2018, c.confirmed_price, 0)) as "Jul", 
sum(if(month(a.end_date) = 8 and year(a.end_date) = 2018, c.confirmed_price, 0)) as "Aug",

d.update_date, d.status_id
from 01c_projects a 
inner join 01c_posts b on a.post_id = b.ID 
inner join 01c_enquairy_product c on a.post_id = c.post_id 
inner join 01c_updates d on a.post_id = d.post_id 
where a.post_id not in (select post_id from 01c_updates where status_id = 25 or status_id = 24)
AND d.id in 
(select id from 01c_updates filter join (select post_id, max(update_date) as update_date from 01c_updates
    group by post_id ) sfilter on 
    filter.post_id = sfilter.post_id
    and filter.update_date = sfilter.update_date)
group by b.post_title
order by a.end_date
```